# Swift - Date change Timezone

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase to show to the user, the workout of the day.
The function is simple:

```
REF_LEADERBOARD.document(gymID).collection("resultsWorkout").whereField("date", isEqualTo: someDateTime).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
      if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
         } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
               // show workout
            }
         }
      }
```

with someDateTime defined like that:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)

let dateShow = "\(year)/\(month)/\(day)"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
let someDateTime = formatter.date(from: "\(dateShow) 00:00")
```

This function is working perfeclty in the USA, but not in France for example.
I think the problem come from the `UTC`:

[image]

I France the `UTC` is not -7 and this function show "no results"...

Do you know how I could do to have a code working for every country in the world?

Comment: Ok, I'm confused. What is your input and what is your expected output?

Comment: Convert date into local time zone

Comment: Dates don't have time zones. They are absolute. Date formatters have time zones. You can use `autoUpdatingCurrent` to format a date for the local time zone or parse a date in the current timezone

Comment: A couple of things jump out at me. First off, in the someDateTime definition, hours and minutes were omitted from the dateShow variable so the formatter won't format those. Secondly and more importantly, it's unclear how the date shown in the question is being written in the first place as someDateTime doesn't represent that string. Perhaps if you can include the code for how the initial date is being generated and stored in Firebase, we can provide better direction. Lastly, if you're trying to get workouts for a day, you may want to consider storing your date as a yyyymmdd string in firebase